# Updating via ajax and getting element values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<div id="colourSelector" class="row">
<input id="backgroundcolor" name="backgroundcolor" size="6" maxlength="6" type="color" style="display: block;">

</div>

<div id="lineHeight" class="row">
<select name="lineHeight" id="lineHeightSelect">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="divlineDemo" class="section row">
<hr id="lineDemo" style="<?=$model->css_style?>" />

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
var colorPicker = $('#backgroundcolor');
var headline = $('#lineDemo');
var lineHeight = $('#lineHeightSelect');

lineHeight.on("change", function(){
    headline.css("height", $(this).val() + "px");
});

colorPicker.on("change", function() {
    headline.css('backgroundColor', $(this).val());
});

});


</script>
```

What I want to do now is get the properties of $model->css_style:

height: 5px; background-color: rgb(0, 253, 255); 
And place them as the default values for backgroundcolor element (background-color: rgb(0, 253, 255)) and lineHeight (height: 5px) --> 5 it must be the default option for this dropdownlist.

I'm sure that there must be some options to do that but I don't know how to do it...

Additionally, I want to take the final value of style of lineDemo to a database field via ajax.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the value of `$model->css_style` ?'

Comment: `<?= $model->css_style ?>` appears to be PHP code--which shouldn't be there. By the time javascript can act on the page, the PHP code should have resolved to whatever the value of `$mode->css_style` is. Try posting the finished page, rather than the .php

Comment: Yes: $model->css_style is yii code. In fact $model->css_style contains a text with background-color and height properties.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what $model->css_style is, I think it is not required in your code. If you want to have default values for this dropdown list, perhaps you could use localstorage instead of a database? You only require a database if you need people other than those on the local machine to access it, but I think localstorage might suffice for your purpose.

What the code below does is essentially what you have done except with a few features added. When the user changes one of the values, the script remembers it. When the user refreshes the page, the saved values will then be set as the starting options for both the colour and the dropdown.

https://jsfiddle.net/domslee/pfsv24yz/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="colourSelector" class="row">
<input id="backgroundcolor" name="backgroundcolor" size="6" maxlength="6" type="color" style="display: block;">

</div>

<div id="lineHeight" class="row">
<select name="lineHeight" id="lineHeightSelect">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="divlineDemo" class="section row">
<hr id="lineDemo" />

</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    var colorPicker = $('#backgroundcolor');
    var headline = $('#lineDemo');
    var lineHeight = $('#lineHeightSelect');

    //If the localStorage exists, use it, otherwise use the current values
    var lineH = localStorage.lineH || lineHeight.val();
    var color = localStorage.color || colorPicker.val();

    headline.css("height", lineH + "px");
    lineHeight.val(lineH);
    headline.css("backgroundColor", color);
    colorPicker.val(color);

    lineHeight.on("change", function(){
        headline.css("height", $(this).val() + "px");

        //Sets the local storage line height to the changed value
        localStorage.lineH = $(this).val();
    });

    colorPicker.on("change", function() {
        headline.css('backgroundColor', $(this).val());

        //Sets the local storage color to the new value
        localStorage.color = $(this).val();
    });

});
```

Comment: Values for hr are saved on a database field in this way: <hr id="lineDemo" style="height: 2px; background-color: red; border: 0;"> </div>

Comment: Sorry, the only thing storage in a database field is: style="height: 2px; background-color: red; border: 0;".

Comment: Are you after the value of $("#lineDemo").attr("style")?

Comment: Yes. This is what I'm looking for. Thanks!